# Как запустить программу на компьютере, чтобы при закрытии скрипта python она не завершалась

Tags: python, ос, subprocess

Необходимо **запустить программу**.
Пробовал через *os.system* и *subprocess.Popen*. Но ни тот, ни другой способ не решает проблему: **При завершении скрипта запущенные программы завершаются.**

Comment: Какая ОС хоть?.

Comment: Windows 7 x64 ///

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте такой вариант, только не уверен, что на Windows сработает, если что попробуйте по ссылке ниже другие варианты:

```
import subprocess
import sys
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe', '-c'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT);
print('finished')
```

Пример взят на [английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058548/8324991)

Comment: Куда можно вводить консольную команду типа:
C:\Program Files\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe

Comment: Попробуйте такие аргументы: `['C:\Program Files\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe', '-c']`

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось дело слегка в другом. Я открывал скрипт не напрямую, а через **SublimeText3**.
И **завершал** тоже через него. ST3 при этом насильно **завершал все процессы**.
Так что все выше перечисленные способы - рабочие.